# MDX: Query Data analysed

Tags: ssas, mdx

In this query i used were clause in that year is 2015 and quarter-[2013]&[Quarter1], how is it possible, and getting result set 10 records. actually result set is not displaying.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test] AS  ( [Measures].[ProgramAssessmentPatientCnt] + [Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt] )
      MEMBER [Measures].[Test1] AS  ( [Measures].[CCMPatientCnt] + [Measures].[CareteamCnt] + [Measures].[CCMPatientCnt] )
SELECT ( ( { [DimEnrollStatus].[EnrollmentStatus].[EnrollmentStatus] } ),
{ [Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt], [Measures].[Test], [Measures].[Test1] } ) ON COLUMNS,
Subset (
  NonEmpty (
    {
      ( { [DimAssessment].[AssessmentText].[AssessmentText] },
      { [DimAssessment].[QuestionText].[QuestionText] },
      { [DimAssessment].[AnswerText].[AnswerText] } )
    },
    { [Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt], [Measures].[Test], [Measures].[Test1] }
  ),
  0,
  10
) ON ROWS
FROM [NavigateCube]
WHERE (
{
  ( { [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationName].&[1044]&[LTC Lincoln Centers] },
  { [DimAnchorDate].[Calender Year].&[2015] },
  { [DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Semester Des].[All] },
  { [DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Quarter Des].&[2013]&[Quarter1] },
  { [DimAnchorDate].[English Month Name Desc].[All] } )
} )
```

Comment: are you saying - currently you get 0 results but you expect 10 OR currently you get 10 results but you expect 0 ?

Comment: @whytheq, no, data is displaying ,even the where clause condition is wrong.

Comment: so I'm confused - 10 rows are displaying - so what is the question?

Comment: @whytheq, actually the where clause is wrong, [Calender Year] = 2015 and [Calendar Quarter Des]=&[2013]&[Quarter1], but it displaying 10 records

Answer (score 0):

Does this return any rows?

```
WHERE 
(
  [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationName].&[1044]&[LTC Lincoln Centers],
  [DimAnchorDate].[Calender Year].&[2015],
  //[DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Semester Des].[All],
  [DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Quarter Des].&[2013]&[Quarter1],
  [DimAnchorDate].[English Month Name Desc].[All]
);
```

Maybe the following:

```
WHERE 
(
  [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationName].&[1044]&[LTC Lincoln Centers],
  {
    [DimAnchorDate].[Calender Year].&[2015],
    [DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Semester Des].[All],
    [DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Quarter Des].&[2013]&[Quarter1],
    [DimAnchorDate].[English Month Name Desc].[All]
  }
);
```

Comment: Still data is coming even i comment that line.

Comment: Yeah result set displaying 10 records, i used subset thus why its displaying 10 records